# Career Profile having bug in showing my Top 10%

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, top-users

My All Top 10% are not showing in My Careers Profile.

[image: With Editing]

[image: Preview]

Why [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) are not showing?

Comment: Did PHP and MySQL become your top-10 tags recently? I had a similar issue a while back that had to do with the data not being synced, but rather cached and updated once every couple of days.

Comment: Who the heck deleted my comment about php suxoring that was why.  Come on people sometimes humor that doesn't point blame at anyone is healthy on a site.  To delete it was wicked evil.

Comment: @Draco18s: I am having PHP and MySql in top 10 from many days. And if you are saying it should have appeared in top 20 % or top 30% at least :P

Comment: I figured, but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the bug report!

This behaviour is by design; it's because you've put PHP and MySQL in [your "Tech you dislike" section](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/somnath.muluk#technologies). Remove them from the "tech you dislike" list and they should reappear in your Stack Overflow percentiles.

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember when did I added Dislike section and mainly PHP and MySql in it. I removed it. Now it's working.